# How to share an object between two classes

Tags: c++, pointers, object, instances

I have two classes, `Foo` and `Bar`. They both contain a pointer to a `Baz` object. I want the `Baz` pointers in both an instance of Foo and an Instance of `Bar` to point to the same `Baz` object.

A `Baz` object has a member called name with getter and setter functions.

A `Foo` object contains a `Bar` object.

A `Bar` object has a method to print the name of the `Baz` object.

The `Baz` objects name must be set in the scope of `Foo`.

This is what I have tried:

In the constructor of `Foo`, it sets the name of this `bazA`, and sets the `bazB` belonging to `bar` to be equal to the `bazA` belonging to `Foo`.

```
//Foo.h
class Foo {
public:
    explicit Foo();
    Baz* bazA;
    Bar bar;
}

//Foo.cpp
Foo::Foo()
{
     this->bazA->setName("hello");
     this->bar.bazB = bazA;
}

//Bar.h
class Bar{
public:
    Baz* bazB;
    void printName ();
}

//Bar.cpp
void Bar::printName ()
{
     std::cout << "name: " << bazB->getName();
    //Should print out "name: hello"
}
```

When I do this:

```
//Main.cpp
Foo foo;
foo.bar.printName();
```

The program crashes because the name member has not been initialised in the `Baz` object that belongs to the `Bar` object.

But the `Baz` object belonging to `Bar` should be the same `Baz` object that belongs to `Foo`, which has had its name set, so it should work.

Why am I getting this error?

How can I correctly share a `Baz` object between the `Foo` and `Bar` classes?

Comment: At some point you need to actually allocate the `Baz` object.

Comment: I have [edited your post](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/49523065/4) to add some formatting to the class names to make it clearer, and I also corrected your typos of `Class` and `Public` since they didn't seem relevant to the question being asked. If I've done so in error, please feel free to add them back as they were.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you have to share the objects is correct: `Foo` creates the `Baz`, then passes it to the `Bar`. The issue is you are not constructing the `Baz` properly:

```
Foo::Foo()
{
     this->bazA->setName("hello"); // crash because bazA hasn't had memory allocated
     this->bar.bazB = bazA; // setting bazB to invalid memory
}
```

Instead, you should just have an object of `Baz` in `Foo`, and share it with `Bar`:

```
class Foo {
public:
    Foo();
    Baz bazA;
    Bar bar;
}

Foo::Foo()
{
     bazA.setName("hello");
     bar.bazB = &bazA;
}
```

Even better, `Bar`'s constructor should take a `Baz` reference instead:

```
class Bar
{
public:
    Bar(Baz& b) : bazB(b){}
private:
     Baz& bazB;
};

Foo::Foo()
    : bazA(), bar(bazA)
{
    bazA.setName("hello");
}
```

Here I assumed that `Class` and `Public` were typos and corrected them.